# Java: Trying to get the percentage of integers, how to round up?

Tags: java, casting, rounding

I have two integer values, x and total. I am trying to find the percentage of x in total as an integer. This is how I am doing it right now:

percentage = (int)((x*100)/total);

The percentage must be an integer. When I do this it always rounds the decimal point down. Is there a simple way to calculate the percentage as an integer so it rounds up if the decimal is .5 or higher?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `Math.round(x * 100.0/total)`.  But note that this returns a long, so a simple cast to `int` will be required.

I put 100.0 to force it to use floating point arithmetic prior to the rounding.

Comment: There is an overloaded method which returns int. So a cast isn't absolutely necessary.

Comment: @DhariniChandrasekaran I believe it returns an int if you pass in a float?  The way I've written it it will pass in a double and return a long.

Comment: @Churk actually I edited my answer because x, 100 and total were all ints so the arithmetic would've all been integers and the call to round would've been a waste of time.  I changed to 100.0 to make it use floating point arithmetic and then added an explanation for it.

Comment: @Churk perhaps you should take a look at the revisions of my answer before making silly false accusations.

Answer (score 5):

```
(int)Math.round(100.0 / total * x);
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Math.round(100.0 / total * x);`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `Math.round((x*100)/total);`

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the problem as `x` and `total` are both integers.  The expression will be evaluated using integer arithmetic and will be "rounded" down before being passed into the round function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard math library in Java.

```
percentage = Math.round(*your expression here*);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add 0.5 for positive values (round to infitity)

```
percentage = (int)(x * 100.0 / total + 0.5);
```

This is faster than using Math.round, but possibly not as clear.

BTW: `100.0 / total * x` might not give the same result as `x * 100.0 / total` as the order of evaluation can change the result for floating point.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Method -

Question : How to round up value of a decimal number(eg : int n =  4.57)

Answer : Math.round(n);

Output : 5 .

Comment: It only partially answer the question. could you elaborate to form a complete answer ?

Comment: It's also not correct; you may want to read the question more carefully, and check out the many existing answers which correctly answer it.